# Returning cleaned_data when overwriting clean() method in Django Model forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I need to overwrite the `clean()` method in a Django Model form to perform additional uniqueness checks on the data entered.

This page gives implementation details:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/ Copied here:

```
 def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()
    cc_myself = cleaned_data.get("cc_myself")
    subject = cleaned_data.get("subject")

    if cc_myself and subject:
        # Only do something if both fields are valid so far.
        if "help" not in subject:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Did not send for 'help' in the subject despite "
                "CC'ing yourself."
            )
```

However I'm confused why this method doesn't `return cleaned_data` at the end of the function? Surely that is the correct thing to do?

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at django's `_clean_form` method:

```
def _clean_form(self):
    try:
        cleaned_data = self.clean()
    except ValidationError as e:
        self.add_error(None, e)
    else:
        if cleaned_data is not None:
            self.cleaned_data = cleaned_data
```

Read the last bullet point on the [forms doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#) **and** especially this bit of the [ModelForm doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-modelform-clean-method).

If the `clean` method raises a `ValidationError`, the error gets added to the forms' errors. 
If the `clean` method has returned anything and threw no errors, the form is going to use that for its `cleaned_data` attribute. Otherwise it will keep its 'old' one.

In your case, all that your `clean` method does, is validating an aspect of the form.

Comment: Is that not a problem if I subclass, override `.clean()`, return nothing, then another form subclasses mine and tries to do similar?  Surely they should all work on `.cleaned_data` rather than `super().clean()`...

Comment: @AdamBarnes Yes, that might be a problem - the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) mention this as well: "The call to super().clean() in the example code ensures that any validation logic in parent classes is maintained..."

Answer (score 0):

The example you are interested in is an override of the `clean` method for related fields. This means that it validates a logic that implicate more than one field. Consider this as the form's `clean` method. Thus, you don't want to return any values in this case.

As the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) says :

"Be careful when doing this in practice, since it can lead to confusing form output. We’re showing what is possible here and leaving it up to you and your designers to work out what works effectively in your particular situation."

It depends on your particular case, but in my experience with overriding `clean` on one particular field, you'll want to return it if the validation passes. Again, this is for only one field.

Here's another example from the doc, but for one field validation:

```
def clean_recipients(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['recipients']
    if "fred@example.com" not in data:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You have forgotten about Fred!")

    # Always return a value to use as the new cleaned data, even if
    # this method didn't change it.
    return data
```

Comment: What do you mean by "consider this as the form's `clean` method"? What are you referring as "this"?

Comment: I think my question may be best answered if I understood what other function use the returned "cleaned_data" once clean() has been called? Or rather, what is "cleaned_data" for?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I'm referring to the `clean` method in your example. When I say the form's `clean` method it is only for educational purpose. I only wanted to underline the fact that forms are a collection of fields and therefore having each their clean` method.
Follow this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) and read the first paragraph.

Comment: Well, in my opinion this is a complete different question. If you expect clear answers, please ask clear questions initially. Sorry my answer is not what  you needed.

Answer (score 0):

In Django < 1.7, `form.clean()` was required to return a dictionary of `cleaned_data`.
This method may still return a dictionary of data to be used, but it’s no longer required.

Comment: Interesting. Is this confirmed somewhere in the django docs?

Comment: In the [Django 1.7 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/releases/1.7/):

The `clean()` method on a form no longer needs to return `self.cleaned_data`. If it does return a changed dictionary then that will still be used.